# unix time in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, date

when they say "we will use unix time", does that mean i should create a column like this ?

```
date DATE
```

or

```
date TIME
```

or

```
date DATETIME
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIX time is expressed as an integer value - [number of seconds since the epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  You'd just want to use an int field for this, not any of the date variants.

Answer (score 3):

A unix time is just a number representing the nr of seconds since 1970. If you want to store that directly, use an INTEGER.

You're likely better off storing this as a DATETIME, as that will facilitate easier querying. Though when inserting data you might need to convert it using the [from_unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)
function.

A DATE stores only the date, not the time(hour/min/secs) and a TIME stores only the time not the date so they're not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Unix-Time is normally seconds from 01-01-1970...means integer.

Comment: so you mean it should be created like this ?
 "date int"
something like that ?

Comment: @sasori yes, exactly, treat it as an unsigned int (32bit :p or else your software will work when others fail in 2038)

Comment: @kb: No!  Unix time is a SIGNED integer.  You have to do this if you want to store dates before 1970.  Hence the Year 2038 problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem